# Eclipse RAP FormToolkit controls ignore CSS style

Tags: java, css, eclipse, eclipse-rap

In my Eclipse RAP application I have a theme with declared CSS styles for controls `Button`, `Combo` ...

I have the following problem, creating controls (e.g. `Button`) with a `FormToolkit` the background and foreground color is ignored.

Normal Button:

```
new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
```

FormToolkit Button:

```
managedForm.getToolkit().createButton(parent, "search", SWT.PUSH);
```

This is the CSS that I use:

```
Button[PUSH] {
    border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    /* fancy test colors */
    background-color: #0000ff;
    color: #00ff00;
}
```

Normal Button
[image: Normal Button]

FormToolkit Button
[image: Form Button]

This is especially bad because the hover effect is ignored as well. Is there a way to enforce the `FormToolkit` to also use the CSS styles?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround, not the desired solution but works for now:

```
// hack to ensure CSS styles are used
toolkit.getColors().setBackground(null);
toolkit.getColors().setForeground(null);
```

If the colors are set to `null`, CSS style is used.